# What is helperGrowEdges function in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, computer-vision, matlab-cvst

I was following a tutorial in matlab documentation at  http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/examples/automatically-detect-and-recognize-text-in-natural-images.html

There they use a function `helperGrowEdges` but I it is not being recognized right now. I verified that I have Computer Vision System Toolbox. I am unable to figure how to implement it. It says it 'Grow the edges outward by using image gradients around edge locations', but I am unable to figure out how to implement is well.

Comment: No downvotes without comments please. I have searched for the problem for 1 day before posting it here

Comment: What version of MATLAB are you using? I'm using R2012a and I don't have this example or function.

Comment: I am using R2013a. Are those functions specific to R2014?

Comment: That's my hunch. Do you have the tutorial in your version's documentation (not online)? That is, can you run `edit TextDetectionExample`?

Answer (score 2):

As hinted out by Naveh, It works those functions are present only in MATLAB 2014 version and not in older versions. 
Older versions do not have that example as well when I try to open edit `TextDetectionExample`

Comment: The various toolboxes for image processing and computer vision have been undergoing major changes in the past few years. MathWorks is trying to keep them updated and useful in this quickly growing field. So it's safest to get to the tutorials and examples through the built-in help rather than the last version's online documentation.

Answer (score 0):

This example first appears in release R2014a.  `helperGrowEdges` is a helper function, which goes with the example.  Unfortunately it does not get published in the documentation.  The only way for you  to see it is to get access to an installation of MATLAB R2014a with the Computer Vision System Toolbox, and do `edit helperGrowEdges`.