# 'helperGrowEdges' function

Tags: matlab

I am trying to run [this example](http://www.mathworks.in/help/vision/examples/automatically-detect-and-recognize-text-in-natural-images.html) in R2013a but it gave me errors.

> Undefined function 'helperGrowEdges' for input arguments of type
>   'double'.

Comment: do you have the computer vision toolbox? You need it to run that function

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23142176/ that function is not in R2013a.

Answer (score 0):

. helperGrowEdges function is not defined in MATLAB 2013a.u need to upgrade ur matlab software to 2014a.after dat your program will run correctly